# How to draw on QGraphicsScene without scaling pen width?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to plot on a QGraphicScene data which can, depending on situation, vary by orders of magnitude. Since the pen I'm using is cosmetic I'd expect the view to be independent of the  magnitude of the data. But what I get instead is this:

Sine wave with noise multiplied by 50000:

[image: scale 50000]

Sine wave with noise multiplied by 50:

[image: scale 50]

However, if I zoom in to either of these plots (same amount of zooming in both), I eventually reach a level when both images look the same:

[image: scale 50000 zoom]
[image]

What is going on here? Why is the width of the pen changing just because the data values are bigger. And why does the scaling disappear when zoomed in?

The code to reproduce this follows. Left clicking on the plot zooms in, right clicking zooms out.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui as QG
from PyQt4 import QtCore as QC

import numpy as n

class ZoomView(QG.QGraphicsView):
    """Zoomable QGraphicsView"""
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QC.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.scale(1.5,1)
        elif event.button() == QC.Qt.RightButton:
            self.scale(1/1.5,1)

class MainUI(QG.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QG.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        button_layout = QG.QHBoxLayout()
        pb3 = QG.QPushButton('add plot')
        button_layout.addWidget(pb3)
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        pb3.clicked.connect(self.scene_maker_singleshot)
        scene = QG.QGraphicsScene()
        view = ZoomView(self)
        view.setTransformationAnchor(QG.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        view.setRenderHint(QG.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        view.setScene(scene)

        self.view = view
        self.scene = scene

    def scene_maker_singleshot(self):
        """Draw scene and fit in view"""
        t1 = 50
        t2 = 100
        QC.QTimer.singleShot(t1, self.make_scene)
        QC.QTimer.singleShot(t2, lambda: self.view.fitInView(self.view.sceneRect()))


    def make_scene(self):
        scale = 50
        #scale = 50000
        noise_amp = 0.2*scale
        points = 1000

        xdata = n.arange(points)
        #generate sine data and random noise
        ydata = n.sin(xdata/(points/10.))*scale +\
                n.random.randint(noise_amp, size=points)
        pen = QG.QPen(QG.QColor("red"))

        for i in xrange(1, xdata.size):
            self.scene.addLine(xdata[i-1], ydata[i-1], xdata[i], ydata[i], pen)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QG.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainUI()
    gui.setFixedSize(500,500)
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this: both scales give exactly the same result for me. This is on Linux, using python 2.7.5, qt 4.8.5, and pyqt 4.10.3.

Comment: Ah. I'm seeing this in OSX. So might be a platform specific 'feature'. I've also found that this behaviour only occurs when two thigns happen at the same time: a) the width of the QGraphicsView widget is less than the number of points being plotted, and b) the amplitude of plot data in vertical axis is larger than in the horizontal

Comment: Tried it in Linux. No problems. I guess I'll have to use a workaround in OSX then. Thanks for testing the code!

Comment: After `pen = QG.QPen(QG.QColor("red"))`, you may need to explicitly state `pen.setCosmetic(True)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just like Mad Physicist told you, set the pen to cosmetic or line-width of 0 (are equal in the behavior) and you have a non-scaling pen.

```
>> pen.setCosmetic(True);
```